# Rails 4 and JQuery - load specific data after navigating

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, navigation

I have no idea where I should begin with the following, that I want to do.

I have a "Welcome Page" where the logged in user gets displayed a list of tickets assigend to him.

In the navigation he can navigate to the "normal" tickets list view, where he gets a list of tickets and if he chooses one in a separate div container the _show view of this single ticket is loaded with this code:

show.js.erb:

```
$("#current_ticket").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tickets/show', locals: { ticket: @ticket } ) %>");
```

Now I want, that if the user clicks on the Ticket on his welcome page, that he gets navigated to tickets_path (which works:

```
<td><%= link_to ticket.name, tickets_path %></td>
```

) and the ticket he clicked on gets loaded in the div container on this tickets_path page.

EDIT:

This is the show part of the tickets controller

```
def show
  @tickets = Ticket.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end
```

Can you help me finding a solution for that?

EDIT:

Sorry, I think you misunderstood what I am wanted to tell you - maybe because of me describing wrong. I have the following views (see the screenshots):

Welcome Page:

[image: Welcome Page]

Tickets "index"

[image: Tickets index]

If a user uses the navigation and clicks tickets he is directed to the tickets index page where all tickets are listed (typically for rails apps). When he now clicks on a ticket, the tickets "show" data gets rendered as a partial in a div on the right via jQuery (the code I posted above).

What I now want is, that if a user is on the welcome page and clicks on a ticket, he should get directed to the tickets index page (tickets_path) -> works, and the ticket he selected on his welcome page should be rendered as partial in the div, just as it works when he navigates to tickets and chooses a ticket there.

That's the point where I am struggling.

Regards
Markus

Comment: Could you provide more info? How did you define the controller?

Comment: I added the show part of the tickets controller.

Comment: Sorry, I added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it myself.
In my welcome view I call the tickes_path with the id of the ticket I want to render

```
<td><%= link_to ticket.name, tickets_path(id: ticket.id) %></td>
```

In the tickets controller index, I find this ticket and save it in a variable

```
  def index
unless params[:id].nil?
  id = params[:id]
  @ticket = Ticket.find(id)
end
```

end

And in the ticket index view, I render the show partial with that ticket from the variable

```
<div id="current_ticket">
  <% unless params[:id].nil? %>
      <%= render partial: 'tickets/show', locals: { ticket: @ticket } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Yeahy!

Answer (score 1):

To make it work:

- Your `link_to` must define `remote` attribute:

  <%= link_to ticket.name, tickets_path, remote: true %>
- Your `show.js.erb` used `@ticket` but you haven't defined it yet, I think this is wrong typo, you may use `@tickets` instead

  ```
  $("#current_ticket").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tickets/show', locals: { tickets: @tickets } ) %>");
  ```
- And you may change `tickets/show` to use `tickets` as well

Btw, your action is wierd, if your expectation is to show all tickets, the action would be `index`, `show` for showing `a ticket`. You may refactor it!

Comment: Sorry, I added more info

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up your index and show methods. The index method is for getting all tickets; the show method is for getting one ticket.

You need to pass the ticket to the ticket path in the link_to statement. In the show method of the controller set ticket to the linked one.

controller

```
def index
  @tickets = Ticket.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end

def show
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render @ticket}
  end
end
```

In your navigation, you should be looping through all the tickets and you can add a link to each ticket. You need to add remote: true to the link so rails knows to make an ajax request.

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <%= link_to ticket.name, ticket_path(ticket), remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

There are a couple of ways to add the individual ticket to the view. You could use a js function to append it to a div or you could create a js.erb partial. See if you can get the above working and check the data being returned in the console so you understand how data is passed

Comment: Sorry, I added more info